# Webpanels en tabs o pestañas

Tags: genexus

¿Cómo podemos hacer de que cada vez que se abra un webpanel en el contentplaceholder, se agregue también en una barra de navegación en forma de pestaña y poder cerrarlas y movernos entre ellas?. Sería como las pestañas de los browsers

Estamos trabajando con gx16 java web, hemos probado con las gxui pero aparentemente ya no está soportado para esta versión.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has intentado y modifica tu pregunta en base a [ask] para que puedas obtener la ayuda deseada en el sitio. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?